# Roslyn: Why do many SymbolDisplay methods have equivalent instance counterparts on ISymbol?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Just curious, I noticed that there seem to be 2 ways of doing the same thing when it comes to stringifying symbols in Roslyn. You can either do:

```
// symbol is type ISymbol
var symbolText = symbol.ToDisplayString();
```

or

```
var symbolText = SymbolDisplay.ToDisplayString(symbol);
```

It's the same story for `ToMinimalDisplayString`, `ToDisplayParts`, and `ToMinimalDisplayParts`. Why did the Roslyn team decide to add both of these APIs instead of making the `SymbolDisplay` static methods internal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SymbolDisplay class is in the CSharp namespace.  It is the actual implementation that formats a symbol in the C# display style.  When you call symbol.ToDisplayString() you are getting the symbol formatting in the symbol's declaring language, which may be VB and not C#.

Comment: I understand a bit more. Why is it that the class was not made internal, though?

Comment: Sometimes you want to format a symbol using the view of a language it was not defined in.  Maybe look at a VB symbol in the style of C#.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks so much for the help!